# If..Else If statements issues using bool operators

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

Hey I try to stay off here as much as possible in order to figure it out myself but this is really bugging me. What I am trying to do is write an if..else if statement that has inputs and outputs. The issue I am coming across is that, the user has to input the data and it has to output what it corresponds to. Also I am trying to use boolean operators to create compound conditions. Here is what the input and output should be.

```
input:               output:

-C# or VB           -Oracle
-Android SDK        -Google
-iOS or XCode       -Apple
-Java and RedHat    -Oracle
-Java               -Sun Microsystems
```

Now I have tried doing it but for some reason I cant get it to allow a alphabetic case to be input. Also how would I incorporate bool into it.

Comment: can you provide the code that you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

public class Program{
   public static void Main(string[] args){
    string word = Console.ReadLine();

    if(word == "C#" || word == "VB"){
       Console.WriteLine("Oracle");//should actually be Microsoft
    }else if(word == "Android SDK"){
       Console.WriteLine("Google");
    }else if(word == "iOS" || word == "XCode"){
       Console.WriteLine("Apple");
    }else if(word.Split()[0] == "Java" && word.Split()[1] == "RedHat"){
       Console.WriteLine("Oracle");
    }else if(word == "Java"){
       Console.WriteLine("Sun Microsystems");
    }
  }
}
```

This is a tedious way to write this program. Instead use a `switch` statement. Also, the `Split()[1]` might actually throw an array out of bound exception, which must be gracefully handled. I will leave that up to you.

Comment: you should put some check to make sure you have at least 2 items in the readline or it would crash in the java redhat if and maybe you should do the split once or maybe just compare the whole string :-)

Comment: Haha I like the comment I agree. So now in order to allow the user to input an response i just need to add

Comment: @Fredou yea, I mentioned that

Comment: why would you convert the language to double? @User

Comment: @Fredou :-P I think you didnot refresh, edited it a while ago :-)

Comment: i saw it after i posted my comment :-)

Comment: Okay so to use words i have to put them in quotes. I am self learning so I tried it on my own but it got the best of me. Also how would i encorporate bool into that

Comment: @User there, try the program out now. Just put it into VS or use Notepad and csc it

Comment: Never mind hahaha Wasnt using my head i see them haha sorry I really appreciate the help

Comment: @User dont forget to put the green check :-)